# How to have consecutive numbering of Theorems, definitions and so on using thmtools

Tags: numbering, theorems, cleveref, thmtools

How can I make the same numeration regardless it is a remark like Theorem or a definition like Theorem or any other `declaredtheorem`.

This is what I have:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Definición, numberwithin=chapter, style=definition]{defn}
\declaretheorem[name=Teorema, numberwithin=chapter]{teo}
\declaretheorem[name=Ejemplos, numberwithin=chapter]{ej}
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma, numberwithin=chapter]{lem}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposición, numberwithin=chapter]{prop}
\declaretheorem[name=Corolario, numberwithin=chapter]{cor}
\declaretheorem[name=Nota, style=remark, numberwithin=chapter]{nota}
\declaretheorem[name=Comentario, style=remark, numberwithin=chapter]{com}
```

I tried using numberlike, for example

```
\declaretheorem[name=Definición, numberwithin=chapter, style=definition]{defn}
\declaretheorem[name=Teorema, numberlike=defn]{teo}
```

but it didn't work.

Here is a short example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Definición, numberwithin=chapter, style=definition]{defn}
\declaretheorem[name=Teorema, numberwithin=chapter]{teo}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{defn}
First definition.
\end{defn}

\begin{teo}
First theorem
\end{teo}

\begin{defn}
Second definition (with numbering of definitions).
\end{defn}

\begin{teo}
Second theorem (I would like it to be number 4)
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

## Edit:

Numberlike works just fine. The problem arises when using `thmtools` package with `cleverref` package.

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet complete, example code demonstrating the problem? (B.t.w., is your user name linked to Charlie Parker?)

Comment: @Bernard There it is. Somewhat, it is related to Art Blakey ;)

Comment: The example I wrote worked just fine. Also, I was able to modify it using numberlike to solve my issue. What caused all the trouble was the use of cleverref package.

Comment: You say `numberwithin=chapter`, but your document uses `article` -- that won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\declaretheorem[name=Teorema,numberwithin=section]{teo}
\declaretheorem[name=Definición,style=definition,numberlike=teo]{defn}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{teo}\label{testteo}
example theorem
\end{teo}
\begin{defn}\label{testdefn}
First definition.
\end{defn}

\cref{testteo} \cref{testdefn}
\end{document}
```

Please note the option `numberlike` to use a shared counter for `teo` and `dfn`. 
I have also replaced `numberwithin=chapter` by `numberwithin=section` as articles don't have chapters. I have also included the `cleveref` package and some `\label` `\cref` examples to demonstrate how it works.